# Intercept page request and add value to it

Tags: posts, pages, request-filter

I am trying to intercept the GET request of a post and add a value to it.

```
function foo($request) {
    $request['vid'] = wp_generate_uuid4();

    return $request;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'foo' );
```

and hope that it would be available later with

```
$_REQUEST['vid']
```

but no access so far any ideas?

Comment: WordPress doesn't add `vid` to the `$_REQUEST` array. Use `get_query_var( 'vid' )` to access the `vid` value..

Comment: @SallyCJ 10x man it works. Put in an answer I will accept it

Comment: Done, @BatMan..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress doesn't add the `vid` to the `$_REQUEST` array. Instead, it's saved in a class property — see [`WP::$query_vars`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/#source) which is an array.

And to access the value of items in that array, use [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var) like so in your case:

```php
$vid = get_query_var( 'vid' );
echo "vid value is $vid";
```

Comment: Is it possible if 2 requests happen almost simultaneously that the second one overrides the value returned by `get_query_var( 'vid' )`  if using it in functions.php when serving a post ?

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but plugins, themes and custom code can change the value at anytime during the same page load/request. E.g. Using `set_query_var( 'vid', 'value' )`.

Comment: Ok Can second page load/request change it for the first being in process for it should trigger the same filter hook? Or they stack 1 after another?

Comment: They stack 1 after another - you get a fresh value on each page load because the data is persistent in the same request only.